# Using Select Distinct in Nested subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a select distinct query which identifies a location ID(pk).  But I want to identify the location name for the end user.  I thought a subquery would return it.  But it returns the value of 1.  Instead of the actual location ID when i run the select distinct query separately (25).  Can't seem to figure out why.

```
SELECT Location.LocationID, Location.Location
FROM Location
WHERE (Location.LocationID)=(
    SELECT Count(*) AS UniqueLocations
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT TransactionLocation
        FROM Transactions
        WHERE (Transactions.TransactionActivity) = [Enter Activity] 
         AND (Transactions.TransactionDate) BETWEEN [Enter the start date:] AND [Enter the end date:]
    )
);
```

Transaction Table

```
TransactionID(pk)| TransactionEmployee|TransactionActivity|TransactionLocation|Date
1 | 1001 | 1 | 25 | 01/01/2014
2 | 1002 | 1 | 25 | 01/02/2014
3 | 1003 | 1 | 25 | 01/03/2014
```

Location Table

```
LocationID(pk)|Location Name
24 | Chicago
25 | Pittsburgh
26 | Boston
```

Thanks
Mike

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you want to achieve. You want the location where the ID equals the number of different transactionlocations where a given activity happened between two given dates ? I can't make sense out of that =/

Comment: Yes, (SELECT Count(*) AS UniqueLocations
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TransactionLocation
FROM Transactions
WHERE (Transactions.TransactionActivity) = [Enter Activity] AND (Transactions.TransactionDate) Between [Enter the start date:] And [Enter the end date:]));   should equal 25.

Comment: Use SO's built-in markdown formatting when possible, as opposed to HTML tags (like <br> for new lines in code formatting).

Comment: Why do you assume it should equal 25 ? As far as I can tell from your example `SELECT DISTINCT TransactionLocation FROM Transactions WHERE (Transactions.TransactionActivity) = [Enter Activity] AND (Transactions.TransactionDate) Between [Enter the start date:] And [Enter the end date:])` will indeed return 25, but the `SELECT COUNT(*)` that you put around it will return 1 because there is only 1 value, namely 25.

Comment: The reason it returns 1 and not 25 is that you use count() and there's only one item returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe you might want something like this:

```
SELECT Location.LocationID, Location.Location
FROM Location
WHERE Location.LocationID IN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT TransactionLocation 
   FROM Transactions
   WHERE Transactions.TransactionActivity = [Enter Activity] 
   AND Transactions.TransactionDate Between [Enter the start date:] And [Enter the end date:]);
```